# How do I hide YouTube Data API key in public repo on GitHub?

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am writing a Python script that uses the YouTube Data API to obtain public data from YouTube.

I want to put up my script on Github and make other users be able to use my script on behalf of my API Key. I know that including my API key in the script is bad. As far as I have understood, OAuth is required to access the private data of users, but I intend to access only public data from YouTube Data API.

So is there a way for me to make my API key hidden to users accessing my project from GitHub while enabling them to use my script, *without them having to make an API key for themselves?*

This is my first Python project using any API, so if there are any errors in how I have understood stuff, do correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that (quote):

> I know that including my API key in the script is bad.

But if you were to observe the specifications of [DTOS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies) (you're compelled to do so in case you need your app to be successfully audited by Google), then you'll find that sharing API credentials is forbidden. The paragraph III.D.1.d of that document says:

> You may share your [*API Credentials*](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies#definition-api-credentials) with agents operating solely on your behalf and under a written duty of confidentiality. However, you must not share or disclose your *API Credentials* to any other third party, allow access to or use of your *API Credentials* by any other third party, or embed your *API Credentials* in open source projects.

Do note the last statement above: it pertains precisely to your use case, specifying that it's not allowed to include your API key in source files published on Github.

Therefore, there's nothing else you can do, but having each user of your Github project using their own API key.

Comment: Thanks for the input. So Oauth is an option for me to make my script usable for others?

Comment: OAuth access and refresh tokens and API keys are API credentials. You're not allowed to share on Github OAuth tokens (that one obtains upon OAuth flows) either.